# How do I require a node module in my client side javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, module, package

I am trying to build a natural language processing bot using javascript and jQuery for the logic and node and express as the framework. I discovered a natural language processing facility that would be extremely useful for my project https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural unfortunately the documentation is sparse and I have only been using node for a couple of weeks.

This is the code I have on my server side app.js

```
 var natural = require('natural'),
 tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer();
 stemmer.attach();
 var express = require("express");
 app = express();
 app.set("view engine", "ejs");
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I am requiring the 'natural' module here but I am unable to use the methods that are outlined in the documentation.

```
var natural = require('natural'),
tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer();
console.log(tokenizer.tokenize("your dog has fleas."));
// [ 'your', 'dog', 'has', 'fleas' ]
```

The method 'tokenizer' is undefined. I have done quite a bit of research on this and looked into using module.export and passing variables through the app.get function for the index.ejs page I am using but I have been unsuccessful so far.

NOTE: The javascript file I am trying to use these methods in is located in the public/javascript directory while the app.js file is located in the main project directory. I have tried to require the 'natural' package directly in the javascript file I am trying to use the methods in but an error was thrown saying require is an undefined method.

here is the package.json file:

```
 {
  "name": "JSAIN",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  "ejs": "^2.3.1",
  "express": "^4.12.3",
  "natural": "^0.2.1",
  "underscore": "^1.8.2"
    }
  }
```

Comment: The natural module says it's for running in the node.js environment.  Unless it has a specific version that runs in a browser, you won't be able to run this in the browser.

Comment: I thought that meant It was for use in a node.js application. Thanks for letting me know I won't be able to use it afterall.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) which allow you to use some npm modules in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Browserify looks like a great workaround so far and a little research has shown that a  few others have also attempted to use it for what I am trying to do. I will learn how to use browserify and with a little luck I can post an answer to my own question in case others are trying to do something similar!

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment into an answer...

The natural module says it's for running in the node.js environment. Unless it has a specific version that runs in a browser, you won't be able to run this in the browser.

Comment: I am actually still confused about what that means exactly? What is the purpose of creating a natural language analyzing module for node.js written in javascript if you can't use it in a node app on the browser??

Comment: @PoPsicle - you collect data in the client and you send it to your server for processing via an ajax call or a form post and the server gives the client back an answer.  That's classic client/server computing.

Answer (score -2):

have you install that module with global mode and have defined that in package.json? Otherwise, try this:

```
npm install -g natural
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried this but am still having the problem, I believe that the comment jfriend00 left may be correct, unfortunately for me.